# Solving an equation with multiple unknowns from different sets of natural numbers

Tags: optimization, diophantine-equations, numerical-optimization

Is it possible to solve an equation:

a*x+b*y+....+c*z-n = 0

where {a, b,..,c, n} are natural numbers and {X, Y,...,Z} are different sets of natural numbers?
Is it possible to find minima if there is no solution?
Please tell me, which branch of mathematics these equations belong to (if any)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

These look like [System of linear equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations). However, you usually require $N$ sets of these equations if there are $N$ unknowns in order to solve them.

Comment: Yes, I understand N equations are needed to find a unique solution in a system of linear equations. I'm looking for the closest "solution", that is the positive minimum - where the x, y, z etc are all from different sets and n is a known constant...wonder if that makes it a non-linear equation :)